# Smooth scrolling over an image

Tags: javascript, css

How can i achieve smooth scrolling over images like the following:

http://axismundi.com/#interior-designers-nyc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is called `parallax` effect using images you can achieve this by setting background image attachment fixed like `background-attachment: fixed;`

you can get idea how to achieve this parallax effect using these links..

http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-parallax-effect-with-css-and-jquery/27274

http://devfloat.net/jquery-parallax-scrolling-tutorials/

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: Thanks very much. This is what i was looking for.

Comment: welcome ... if you found my answer helpful then you can tick right sign as accepted answer or upvote the answer so other users can get idea this answer helps you or not..

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your backgruond image by following this code in css.

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```